# How to concatenate array of string elements into a string

Tags: arrays, string, delphi, string-concatenation, delphi-2007

How should an array of string be converted into string (With separator char)? I mean, is there some system function I can use instead of writing my own function?

Comment: What Delphi version?

Comment: @KenWhite: Version is Delphi2007

Comment: You can use TStringList with Delimiter. Or you can write you own function. I'd shun TStringList. No need to make an instance for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are using Delphi 2007 you have to do it you self:

```
function StrArrayJoin(const StringArray : array of string; const Separator : string) : string;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := low(StringArray) to high(StringArray) do
    Result := Result + StringArray[i] + Separator;

  Delete(Result, Length(Result), 1);
end;
```

Simply traverse the array and concat it with your seperator.

And a small test example:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption :=StrArrayJoin(['This', 'is', 'a', 'test'], ' ');
end;
```

Comment: I wrote my own function! Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: Not ideal in terms of speed

Comment: But readable and easy to understand for anyone who isn't very familiar to Delphi and pointer-stuff

Comment: Please fix the bug in last line of fn body (you delete 1 symbol, but separator is unlimited string).
Correct code should be:
`if (Length(Result)>0) then Delete(Result, 1 + Length(Result) - Length(Separator), Length(Separator));`
Why didn't anyone notice this before?  at least 9 people have this bug.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using a more recent version of Delphi you could use `TStringHelper.Join`, see: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Join

```delphi
Writeln(String.Join(',', ['String1', 'String2', 'String3']));
```

Output would be: `String1,String2,String3`

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is not ideal in terms of speed, especially if multiple threads are used. This approach is 3x faster on single core, and scales well on SMP.

```
function JoinStrings(const s: array of string; Delimiter: Char): string;
var
  i, c: Integer;
  p: PChar;
begin
  c := 0;
  for i := 0 to High(s) do
    Inc(c, Length(s[i]));
  SetLength(Result, c + High(s));
  p := PChar(Result);
  for i := 0 to High(s) do begin
    if i > 0 then begin
      p^ := Delimiter;
      Inc(p);
    end;
    Move(PChar(s[i])^, p^, SizeOf(Char)*Length(s[i]));
    Inc(p, Length(s[i]));
  end;
end;
```

Speed test:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, StrUtils, Classes;

function StrArrayJoin(const StringArray: array of string; const Separator: string) : string;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := low(StringArray) to high(StringArray) do
    Result := Result + StringArray[i] + Separator;
  Delete(Result, Length(Result), 1);
end;

function JoinStrings(const s: array of string; Delimiter: Char): string;
var
  i, c: Integer;
  p: PChar;
begin
  c := 0;
  for i := 0 to High(s) do
    Inc(c, Length(s[i]));
  SetLength(Result, c + High(s));
  p := PChar(Result);
  for i := 0 to High(s) do begin
    if i > 0 then begin
      p^ := Delimiter;
      Inc(p);
    end;
    Move(PChar(s[i])^, p^, SizeOf(Char)*Length(s[i]));
    Inc(p, Length(s[i]));
  end;
end;

var
  TestData: array of string;

type
  TTestThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    Func: Boolean;
    Count: Integer;
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

procedure TTestThread.Execute;
var
  dtStart: TDateTime;
  i: Integer;
begin
  dtStart := Now;
  Count := 0;
  repeat
    for i := 1 to 1000 do
      if Func then
        JoinStrings(TestData, ';')
      else
        StrArrayJoin(TestData, ';');
    InterlockedIncrement(Count);
  until Now > dtStart + 1/86400;
end;

procedure TestSmp(CpuCount: Integer; Func: Boolean);
var
  i, c: Integer;
  Threads: array of TTestThread;
begin
  SetLength(Threads, CpuCount);
  for i := 0 to High(Threads) do begin
    Threads[i] := TTestThread.Create(true);
    Threads[i].Func := Func;
    Threads[i].Resume;
  end;
  c := 0;
  for i := 0 to High(Threads) do begin
    Threads[i].WaitFor;
    Inc(c, Threads[i].Count);
    Threads[i].Free;
  end;
  WriteLn(c);
end;

procedure Init();
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(TestData, 1000);
  for i := 0 to High(TestData) do
    TestData[i] := DupeString('x', Random(32));
end;

begin
  try
    Init();
    Assert(StrArrayJoin(TestData, ';') = JoinStrings(TestData, ';'));
    TestSmp(1, false);
    TestSmp(1, true);
    TestSmp(4, false);
    TestSmp(4, true);
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Results: on a quad-core CPU JoinStrings is 12x faster.

```
StrArrayJoin 1 thread:  55
JoinStrings  1 thread:  184
StrArrayJoin 4 threads: 58
JoinStrings  4 threads: 713
```

Answer (score 3):

In delphi for .NET you can use the framework [Join](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Method.asp?NameSpace=System&Class=String&Type=Class&Method=Join) function , while if you don't want to rely on the .NET framework then you can link the open source JCL library : take a look at the [IJclStringList interface](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:IJclStringList) of the library .

```
JclStringList.Join(',');
```

Otherwise as someone suggested in comments you can simply use a TStringList this way :

```
arrayList.Delimiter := ',';
arrayList.QuoteChar := '';
joinedArray := arrayList.DelimitedText;
```

*Note that latest version of Delphi XEs*(since XE3 if I well remember) *have a TStringHelper class that adds the [Join](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Join) method to the String class* :

```
 class function Join(const Separator: string; const Values: 
IEnumerator<string>): string; overload; static;
```

Comment: You want the `Join` overload that accepts an open array of `string`. Of course, `Join`, being part of the string helper, is implemented very poorly. The `IEnumerable<string>` version is broken until XE8, and the efficiency is poor. It's frustrating that Emba's recent RTL quality is so poor.

Comment: Actually setting QuoteChar to '' shouldn't work (at least in Delphi 11 it doesn't seem to be supported when doing TStringList.Create). One has to use a null character (aka #0) instead. See https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TStrings.QuoteChar